# How to check in R if a value is measured in all experiments?

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing gene name, condition and the measured expression for a lot of different genes. I need to select only the genes for which the expression has been measured under all 20 conditions. What would be the easiest way to do this?

I thought it would be an option to select the genes that are present in exactly 20 rows in the data frame. However, some genes have been measured multiple times under 1 condition. I'm not sure how to take this into account.

Comment: Please share a small sample of your data, preferably in a copy/pasteable format. `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:10, ]))` is a good start, but it's best if you choose a representative sample if, say, the first 10 rows are all one gene or one condition. Sharing 2-3 genes with 2-3 conditions would be ideal so we can demonstrate a solution.

Comment: One good method would be with `dplyr`, something like `data %>% group_by(gene) %>% filter(n_distinct(conditions) == 20)`, but there could be more going on depending on your data structure or other things... without a sample of data it's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!